# use ngx-translate in .ts file

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I want to use a translation in sidemenu titles, I read [this tutorial](https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/internationalize-and-localize-your-ionic2-app-with-ngtranslate) and I solve it as:

```
translate.get('HOME').subscribe(res => {

this.pages= [
 {title: res ,                  component: HomePage},
 {title: 'My Account',               component: MyAccountPage},
 {title: 'Changer Pass' , component: ChangePasswordPage}
]
```

It works, but the problem is that I want t get many title from the translation file to set them as sidemenu titles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please do not use the `forkJoin` operator in this case. ngx-translate supports fetching multiple translations at once by passing an array of keys to the `get()` method like this:

```
translate.get(['HOME', 'MY_ACCOUNT', 'CHANGE_PASSWORD']).subscribe(translations => {
  this.pages= [
    { title: translations.HOME, component: HomePage},
    { title: translations.MY_ACCOUNT, component: MyAccountPage},
    { title: translations.CHANGE_PASSWORD, component: ChangePasswordPage}
  ];
})
```

**Edit**:

[Here](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#methods) you can find all supported methods and their signature.

Comment: Why is `forkjoin` not a good fit here? And any reference or doc for above usage, please?

Comment: I don't say it is a "bad" solution, works just as well. But I just don't think its worth importing another rxjs operator if the feature is built right into ngx-translate.

Comment: Yep, Good catch. Hope you'll put this ref in your answer too. +1 https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#methods

Comment: I've deleted my answer since this is the best way to solve the OP. Thanks for sharing @David. +1

Comment: @David: hey actually in my scenario language changes on the fly so if I will use the  get method it will not reflect the updated language so for that I need to use stream method is it good ?

Answer (score 0):

[@David](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46176818/6685807) thank you for your inspiration.

also you can use something like this:

```
translate.get(['Home', 'My Account', 'Change Password']).subscribe(translations => {
  this.pages= [
    { title: translations['Home'], component: HomePage},
    { title: translations['My Account'], component: MyAccountPage},
    { title: translations['Change Password'], component: ChangePasswordPage}
  ];
})
```