# ngx-translate with multiple translations at once and dynamic text on ts file

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3, ngx-translate

I would like to implement dynamic elements into multiple translations with ngx-translate, in order to fuse [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46173238/use-ngx-translate-in-ts-file) (multiple translations) :

```
this.translate.get(['HOME', 'MY_ACCOUNT', 'CHANGE_PASSWORD']).subscribe(res => {
      showToast(res.HOME,res.MY_ACCOUNT,res.CHANGE_PASSWORD);
});
```

with [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155989/ngx-translate-with-dynamic-text-on-ts-file) (dynamic text) :

```
this.translate.get('HOME', {value: 'test_HOME'}).subscribe(res => {
      showToast(res);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you came up with your own solution by now, but I did something like:

```
public translateTableHeadings(stringArr: string[] = []): Observable<string[]> {
        const sub = new Subject<string[]>();

        const obs$ = Observable.from(stringArr);

        obs$
            .map(aString=>
                this.translate.get(aString)
            )
            .toArray()
            .takeUntil(sub)
            .subscribe(translatedStrings=> {
                sub.next(translatedStrings);
                sub.complete();
            });

        return sub.asObservable();
}
```

While I'm aware of the changes done to the `get` function on the `TranslationService` catering for multiple translation strings as an input, I had a specific use case where I needed to run code for each one after it was translated (ie, I added a `.map` to the `this.translate.get(...` and ran some code in there.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

asper the type annotation of the `get` method in `TranslateService` you can specify `interpolateParams` as the second parameter.

```
TranslateService.get(key: string | string[], interpolateParams?: Object): Observable<any>
```